Sorting a Python Dictionary by "Date" keeping the integrity of the dictionary
Upon doing some research online there does not seem to by any simple way to just order a dictionary
My Dict contains a list with each name being the key
dummy_data = {
    "Date":["01/24/2029","10/28/2027", "01/24/2024","03/24/2024"],
    "Company Name":["Mcdonalds", "Burger King", "KFC","Popeyes"],
    "File_name_location":["C/Documents/Files/invoice1.pdf", "C/Documents/Files/invoice1.pdf","C/Documents/Files/invoice1.pdf"],
}

As you see with the above I have a field called Date which list the dates in random order. I would like to get the least to greatest dates but then also ensuring the "Company Name" as well gets moved around
Based on some information I would have to change the Date to a datetime which I did by
for index, result in enumerate(dummy_data["Date"]):
    dummy_data["Date"][index] = datetime.strptime(dummy_data["Date"][index], "%m/%d/%Y").date()

I know there is a much faster way on changing the Date to a date very quickly with lambda but I am not familar with lambda enough just yet.
In any case another issue is that I would also like if possible to keep my date with the slash if that was even possible but it seems that it may not even possible because the .date() returns it in this format **(01-24-2029) ** but also I would now have to wrap the datetime in a str otherwise the Date list will have objects of datetime in them rather than the string data.
My ultimate goal is

Sort by Date and making sure "Company Name" also keeps the correct index of the above
If possible keep the dates with the slashes if not possible then no worries.

I know there is an OrderedDict class but I am not familiar with this as I believe this uses some sort of function like a lambda as a parameter.

If it even matters why
The reason I would like to sort by dates is because these dates are being pulled in by some invoices which I am using a PDFREADER to read the dates and then I would to ultimately merge the pdfs together but it will be merged by the date of the file meaning the file with the "least" date will be put on top or bottom depending on what I want. In any case if anyone feels like they have some sort of workaround please get back to me.

also for whatever reason I did try
sorted_val = str(sorted(dummy_data["Date"]))

I double checked the above and it actually did not sort anything

"I know there is a much faster way on changing the Date to a date very quickly with lambda but I am not familar with lambda enough just yet." no, lambda expressions are just syntactic sugar, the create normal function objects, there is nothing you can do with a lambda expression (and the resulting function object) that you cannot do with a function object created with a function definition statement

anyway, do all the keys have a list of the same length, or can one of the lists be not the same length as the others, as is the case with the key "File_name_location" in your example data?

as an aside, you should stick with datetime.datetime (datetime.date) objects. Those are much more useful to work with than strings. Then, when you need a string, just formate the datetime/date object.

Yes all keys will actually will have a value so each list will be the same size as the next list since I do have to export it to CSV using pandas but the guy who answered it does work actually if I change the data to a list of dicts rather than the other way around but I just do not understand that lambda function

You don't need pandas to create a csv.

Anyway, please make sure you example actually reflects your data

So you don't really want to sort the dictionary -- you want to sort the values of the dictionary?

Well, the question was closed as a duplicate, but here is a gist of how to do this relatively easily: https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/b3ae481e896c4a5dafdc582de8365550
Also, I added how to write a csv from your dictionary using the standard library. you don't pandas

@juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry about the way I put the data my data reflects very closely the data here which is why I thought it was fine but in this case this also does not work as I wanted it seems chris with the answer below is seems like the best answer because it sort the entire dict but first making the dict into a list instead

Parallel lists often cause confusion. It's much easier if this is a list of dictionaries rather than a dictionary of lists.
dummy_data = [
    {
        "Date": "01/24/2029",
        "Company Name": "Mcdonalds"
    },
    {
        "Date": "10/28/2027",
        "Company Name": "Burger King"
    },
    {
        "Date": "01/24/2024",
        "Company Name": "KFC"
    },
    {
        "Date": "03/24/2024",
        "Company Name": "Popeyes"
    }
]

So that now we can use a simply str.split to sort.
sorted(
    dummy_data, 
    key=lambda x: ((y := [int(z) for z in x['Date'].split('/')])[2], y[0], y[1])
)

And we get:
[{'Date': '01/24/2024', 'Company Name': 'KFC'}, 
 {'Date': '03/24/2024', 'Company Name': 'Popeyes'}, 
 {'Date': '10/28/2027', 'Company Name': 'Burger King'}, 
 {'Date': '01/24/2029', 'Company Name': 'Mcdonalds'}]

You just need to figure out how to move from your data structure to this one. That should be very straightforward.
Breaking down the lambda
[int(z) for z in x['Date'].split('/')]

This is a list comprehension. We split the date string on '/' but each thing is a string, so we get the int version of it. For '10/03/2023' for instance, we now have a list [10, 3, 2023].
We then use the "walrus operator" to assign that list comprehension to y while also returning that list. We could just write:
([int(z) for z in x['Date'].split('/')][2], [int(z) for z in x['Date'].split('/')][0], [int(z) for z in x['Date'].split('/')][1])

But that's both doing too much work, and is annoying to look at. The walrus operator means we only need to call str.split once.
We then build a tuple of the 3rd element (at index 2 since Pyth0on lists are zero-indexed) , the first element, and the second element. This represents year, month, date.
By using this as the key we sort the dictionaries first on year, then month, then date.

I actually been reading the code over and over there two things I cant really grasp the int(z) and also the last part y[0] and y[1]

I have edited with more explanation.

To be honest I give you a lot of props because you literally did not use any other module to do this I give this 1000/1000 if I could but the issue is that I would never have guessed that with the walrus operator you can just use a comma and call the the index of 0 and 1 by adding a little comma. in any case I did use a different expression which was a bit shorter and just easier for me personally to write more so than read. regardless appreciate the huge help

sorted(dummy_data, key= lambda x: datetime.strptime(x["Date"], format))

The above is what I used but I did ( from datetime import datetime) and then this function just seemed shorted regardless I used a bit of your formular and some others from online to combine to together into this as I can personally read this in my opinion
